# Concatenating a Week Start Date to a Google Form Title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I have a Google Form that's used as a weekly sign-up sheet. I need a form for each week of the year and my current workflow involves manually duplicating and renaming the form each week.

I'm attempting to use some automation to speed up this workflow and reduce the amount of manual work. I have the following Google Apps Script that I'm using that makes a copy of the original Form.

```
  function duplicateForm() {
  var templateformId = '1WsWb-VHK36Hm5YY5YaZaA14RdM2GhIujPwqmxiFDMk8';
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1zWmCz9BaJwctdcCfutUsvAs1_qQhledk");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(templateformId).makeCopy("Training Requests 2023", destFolder);
  var fileId = file.getId()
}
```

Ideally I'm wanting to rename each new form with a week start date e.g.

1. Training Requests 2023 - 02/01/2023
2. Training Requests 2023 - 09/01/2023
3. Training Requests 2023 - 16/01/2023

And so on until it gets to the last Monday of the current year.

Does anyone know a way of achieving this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi sorry for any confusion caused. Basically, I have a Google Form and I want it to make lots of copies of it, so I have one form for each week of the year. I want each form to be renamed with the week start date. For example, if I created forms for the first 3 weeks of 2023, they'd be called:
Training Requests 2023 - 02/01/2023,
Training Requests 2023 - 09/01/2023,
Training Requests 2023 - 16/01/2023.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function duplicateForm() {
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  const files = destFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  let d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  let found = false;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if (file.getName().includes(d)) {
      found = true;
    }
  }
  if (new Date().getDay() == 1 && !found) {
    DriveApp.getFileById("formid").makeCopy(`Training Requests 2023 - ${d}`, destFolder);
  }
}

function createduplicateTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "duplicateForm").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("duplicateForm").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, I tried running this code in Google Apps Script using a time-based trigger of generating a new form every minute. This created the duplicate forms, but the issue is they all had the same name of 'Training Requests 2023 - 11/28/2022'. Is this due to the script looking for the next available Monday? I wanted it to create a form for every week of the year ideally. Any ideas if I can achieve this in one iteration of the script? Or, it this designed to be ran once each week?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this new code, but I'm still getting the same result, which is duplicated forms but with exactly the same name e.g. Training Requests 2023 - 11/28/2022, Training Requests 2023 - 11/28/2022, Training Requests 2023 - 11/28/2022... Could this be something to do with the fact that I'm testing it using a trigger to generate a new form every minute?